# Accessing a html tag attribute in Django template expression

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

There is a html element:

```
<input type="text" id="someInput" name="someInput"></input>
```

It's value is set in JavaScript:

```
var tbIndx = 10;
document.getElementById("someInput").value = tbIndx;
```

Now,I want to construct a Django for-loop which would use the value of the html tag described above.Something like this:

```
{% for i in val %}//val is the innerHTML of the input box described above.
//code
{% endfor %}
```

Can we access a value like this in a Django template?Please suggest some methods for achieving this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do this. Django for loop will run only for values passed from context in view.py. Better you submit the input value using Ajax. And return it to run in template from Ajax response.

Comment: can't make an Ajax call,the JS,html code and Django expression all are in a single file

Comment: @ssharma if js code is in the same file you can make Ajax call to a view right?

Comment: there is no view for it,the whole html comes from  a database table.

Comment: Then better make a view if you want to use it django for loop. Otherwise update the div using Jquery .html() with someInput value.

Comment: what would be the use of Jquery.html?

Comment: To update the div with the Val of input tag that you are trying to achieve using django for loop.

Comment: django for loop is not for updating,there is a div which I can't pre-determine how many times to be created,this for loop will create the div dynamically different number of times.

Comment: If you can't pre-determine how many times to create the div? Then how you expect for loop to know many times he has to iterate? You need to work on view to pass value through context and your django for loop will iterate that many times and create those many div's for you.

Comment: You still don't want to use views, then use javascript append functions to add those many div's to a parent div.

Comment: "Then how you expect for loop to know many times he has to iterate",that is why there is a for loop. wouldn't this achieve the same functionality as in C++ like for(int i=0;i<val;i++)?

Comment: You can run for loop in javascript like this
    for (i =0; i <= tbIndx; i++) { 
*your code to create those many divs 
}